# Strange behavior for loop over a million

Tags: c

I am trying to do some recursive multiplication.

When the iteration number is more than 1 million, the completion time started to go up, why?

[image]

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float num; 
unsigned long i, j;
clock_t start, end;

int main(void)
{
    start = clock();

    for (j = 0; j<10000000; j++){

        num = 1.000001E30f; 

        for (i = 0; i<100; i++){

            num = num * 0.999915454854432f;

            if (num == 0){
                printf("zero\n");
            }
        }
    //printf("%e\n", num);
    //printf("%ld\n", j);
    }
    end = clock();
    float cpu_time_used = ((float)(end - start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f",  cpu_time_used);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with GCC 7.3 on Windows 10

Comment: What is the data type of i, j, num? Are they going out of range?

Comment: Where is the recursive part?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including the code you used to benchmark it

Comment: Hi, i have edited the question, some parts of the code are not copied previously, i & j are unsigned long, and num is float.

Comment: I do not see anything peculiar with the numbers. Please provide a program that actually allows changing the limits or have inline functions or sth that runs the program with different parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You keep multiplying an accumulator by 0.999915454854432f, thus bringing the value closer and closer to zero. You might be getting so close to zero that it becomes a [*denormal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) representation. That may trigger slower execution in the floating point hardware and can be a source of surprising performance bloat. Just a wild guess!

See the "Performance Issues" section in the above Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering the my question and not marking my question "off-topic" like the others. Indeed, the number goes into denormal range after close to 2 millions loop. It's a correct guess!